# Extract an image from an object JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, php

i'm trying to send an image that i took from a database and i would like to send that image, using a WebApi written in PHP with JSON to a Java program; the following lines are an extract from PHP program:

```
$img = file_get_contents($stringPath);
$array = ["immagine" => base64_encode($img)];
echo json_encode($array);
```

in the following JAVA program i use restlet framework:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("link to the webApi");``
String retur = resource.get().getText();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(retur);
```

How can i extract from the JSON object the image that i sent from the PHP progra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correct you just have to do the reverse step like you are doing in your php code.

```
byte[] content = Base64.decodeBase64(obj.getString("immagine"));
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bais);
```

Comment: @JacopoTerrinoni I'm glad to hear this. You can accept the answer to help others to find a solution.